# Read file from SFTP as array of byte without downloading it to a file C#

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, sharpssh

I am using SharpSSH to access SFTP. I don't want to download the remote file, I just want to read its data as a string or array of byte. In SharpSSH, I just found function to download the file from source folder to another folder.
Is there any way to read the data from file without downloading it either by SharpSSH or other free library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Do not use SharpSSH, it is a dead project.*

With the [SSH.NET library](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET), you can use the `SftpClient.DownloadFile`:

```
void DownloadFile(string path, Stream output, Action<ulong> downloadCallback = null);
```